# Is it possible to return a map from NodeJS request?

Tags: node.js, dictionary

I'm trying to return an array and a map from my NodeJS request.

```
let returnData = {
    credits: [],
    details: new Map()
}
const data = req.body.data || req.body;
const credits = await CheckRegister.getReconcileCredits({
    propertyID: data.propertyID,
});
returnData.credits = credits;
for(const c of credits) {
    const paymentDetails = await TenantTransactions.getPaymentDetails(parseInt(c.CheckRegisterID));
    let description = '';
    for(const pd of paymentDetails) {
        description += `Tenant: ${pd.tenantFName} ${pd.tenantLName} .&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount: $${parseFloat(pd.TransactionAmount).toFixed(2)}<br/>`;
        returnData.details.set(parseInt(c.CheckRegisterID), description);
    }
}
return res.json(returnData);
```

When I check it in postman, the array data is returned, but the map is an empty object. However, when I `console.log()` the map before returning, it is a valid map with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning Map object is not enough. It's required to convert Map to valid json.

```
returnData.details = Object.fromEntries(returnData.details)
return res.json(returnData)
```

Comment: This works like a charm! However, if one has map with values like `'4': 10, '2': 5, '3': 2`, it will reorder it when transformed as object. The result will be `'2': 5, '3': 2, '4': 10`. This is due to the automatic order of the objects in js when the property/key is numeric-like value... If one add a prefix, it will keep the initial order.